# Can't read my data while knitting to dashboard from Rmd

Tags: r, r-markdown, dashboard

I'm trying to knit my Rmd file to a Dashboard and this message pops up:
[image]

The weird thing is that if I run my code in the Rmd I get what I want and the object 'mapas_regiones' is found.

```
mapas_regiones %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(aes(geometry = geometry, fill = as.factor(treatment)))  +
  labs(title = "Regiones tratadas",  
       caption = "Fuente: Elaboración propia en base de reportes de Carabineros y chilemapas") +
  coord_sf()   +
  theme_void() + geom_sf_label_repel(aes(label = nombre_region), force = 20, nudge_x = -20, seed = 100, size =2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("skyblue2", "dodgerblue4")) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Treatment")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.8), plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Running this code gives me my wanted output:
[image]

It might be relevant to say that the object 'mapas_regiones' is a dataset that uses geometry (not latitude or longitude) as the geographical reference that is used to plot the map.

I appreciate your time and help!

Comment: yes! The object is created in the environment. I created the dataset in the code from a library and another dataset.

Comment: If I understand the issue, you are able to run the chunk by itself and not by knitting

Comment: Exactly. That's why it's so confusing.

Comment: Can you try on a clean R session with all objects removed from the environment.

Comment: Also, if you can show a small reproducible example that shows the issue, would be able to test

Comment: I am suspecting that the object was created in your global environment and thus it worked while individually running, while in the knit, it is using from a different env i.e. a new env and there was no object

Comment: In the same code I have about 30 other datasets that I have created in the Rmd and I only get trouble with 'regiones_mapas'. I'm running everything from scratch with all objects removed from the environment.

Comment: Also, check for any spelling/lowercase/uppercase issue while creating the object